# Como usar distinct Count y Join en codeigniter entre 2 Base de Datos

Tags: sql, codeigniter

Hola necesito llevar esta consulta SQL a codeigniter

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT uh.carrera.alumno_id)
From alumno.listado
Inner Join uh.carrera ON uh.carrera.alumno_id = alumno.listado.id
```

La consulta en SQL funciona perfectamente, lo que no se hacer la relación entre 2 base de datos en codeigniter, he probado muchas variantes pero ninguna con resultados, todas con errores, el objetivo es contar la cantidad de alumnos que hay en esa universidad.

Comment: Pueden serrar el tema que ya resolví el problema, lo solucione por el momento con $this->alumno->select('id')->from('listado')->join('uh.carrera', 'uh.carrera.alumno_id = listado.id', 'INNER')->distinct('uh.carrera.alumno_id')->count_all_results();

Comment: Mi consejo sería que respondas a tu pregunta agregando el código que solucionó tu problema y explicando como lo hiciste

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione con:

```
$this->alumno->select('id')
    ->from('listado')
    ->join('uh.carrera', 'uh.carrera.alumno_id = listado.id', 'INNER')
    ->distinct('uh.carrera.alumno_id')
    ->count_all_results();
```